# "no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<'" error when compiling in Linux, VS doesn't present this error

Tags: c++

For some reason my code works in Visual Studio but not in the Linux compiler and gives me an error in Linux saying

```
test_main.cpp:65: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<'
```

With tons of lines inside of [] my overloading code

```
String String::operator + (const String & s) const {
String temp;
temp.head = ListNode::concat(head,s.head);
return temp;
}
```

my concat code

```
String::ListNode * String::ListNode::concat(ListNode * L1, ListNode * L2)
{
return L1 == NULL ? copy(L2): new ListNode(L1->info, concat(L1->next, L2));
}
```

code testing it

```
String firstString("First");
String secondString("Second");
cout << "+: " << firstString + secondString << endl;
```

declaration

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, String & l);
```

Body

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, String & l)
{
l.print(out);
return out;
}
```

Print method

```
void String::print(ostream & out)
{
    for (ListNode * p = head; p != nullptr; p = p->next)
        out << p->info;
}
```

In my Visual Studio 2015 environment this print `FirstSecond` and doesn't give an error like in Linux and I have no idea why

Comment: Where's your output operator declared/defined. Post a [MCVE] please to get a concise diagnosis of your problem.

Comment: How does your overloaded output operator look like? Does it take the `String` argument as a *constant reference* (i.e `String const&` or `const String&`)? And don't try to simplify the error, please post the complete and unedited error output, including any informational notes.

Comment: Heres the output operator and the full error message is gigantic over 100 lines long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the output operator:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, String & l);
```

The result of the operation `firstString + secondString` is a *temporary* object, and non-constant references can't bind to temporary object.

You need to change your function to take a reference to a constant object, e.g.

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, String const & l);
//                                           ^^^^^
//                              Note use of `const` here
```

Comment: The reason why it works on Windows is because MSVC implements an extension to C++ that allows temporaries to bind to non-const references.

Comment: Thanks :) will accept your answer in 5 minutes when it lets me learning this for school so Im curious is there any reason visual studios doesn't care about this but Linux does? and also is there a way to fix this in my + operator? I understand that the reason is im making a temporary variable inside it that is getting deconstructed but im not sure what a good way around that is my professor gave me the header file with all the declarations so If there is a way not to change the parameter of << I would like to try it